# Kendo UI for Angular 2 with System.js

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to get the kendo UI for Angular 2 hooked up to my app and I am having some issues.

Here is my system.config.js:

```js
map: {
    // our app is within the app folder
    app: 'app',

    // angular bundles
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

    //kendo components
    '@progress/kendo-angular-intl': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-intl',
    '@progress/kendo-angular-grid': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
    '@telerik/kendo-intl': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-intl',

    // other libraries
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    'ng-block-ui': 'npm:ng-block-ui/bundles/umd'
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
    app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'ng-block-ui': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": { main: './dist/npm/main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@telerik/kendo-intl': { main: './dist/npm/main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@progress/kendo-angular-intl': { main: './dist/npm/main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
```

In my module definition:

```js
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

...

imports: [
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
 BrowserModule,
 BlockUIModule,
 GridModule
],
```

When I try to run the app, I get:

```js
SystemJS) Unexpected token <
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (http://dev-app.com/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/grid.component.js:26:28)
    at eval (http://dev-app.com/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/grid.component.js:683:4)
    at eval (http://dev-app.com/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/grid.component.js:684:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
Evaluating http://dev-app.com/@progress/kendo-angular-l10n
Evaluating http://dev-app.com/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/grid.component.js
Evaluating http://dev-app.com/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/grid.module.js
Evaluating http://dev-app.com/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/main.js
Evaluating http://dev-app.com/app/app.module.js
Evaluating http://dev-app.com/main.js
Error loading http://dev-app.com/main.js"
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the same problem Progress has the complete list of mappings to add in `systemjs.config.js`

[system.js configuration](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular-quickstart/blob/master/src/systemjs.config.js)

Depending on the components to be used some of the mappings will apply

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, it seems that the problem happens during evaluation of the l10n (localization) package:

> Evaluating http://dev-app.com/@progress/kendo-angular-l10n

This is caused by a recent change in the Kendo components that requires the localization package to be loaded, too. Adding the following to the SystemJS configuration should help:

```
map: {
    '@progress/kendo-angular-l10n': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-l10n'
},
packages: {
    '@progress/kendo-angular-l10n': {
        main: './dist/npm/main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex,  I cannot find k10n package.  I see l10n though.  Is this the package you are referring to?

Comment: I tried to take the suggested approach, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: My bad, the package name is `l10n`, from localization. If the above does not help, please send a sample project that shows the problem via a support ticket.

Comment: Alex,  I have submitted the related project files in the ticket I have open in the helpdesk.  Let me know if you need more info.  Thank you